# Python Ternary Style: Is this good or bad style?

Tags: python, styles

The following line is practically readable like a sentence. It also seems very Pythonic to do it this way, but again I'm knew to this language and just looking for style tips.

```
for state in states: score += penalty if state == bad else bonus
```

Comment: See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: The ternary operator, IMO, reads better if the `if` portion is the "likely" case, with the `else` part occurring rarely, or at least significantly less often. If the two cases are equally likely, then an explicit `if-else` statement is preferable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That style would not be appropriate at my workplace. Consider this snippet from [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are
> generally discouraged.
>
> Yes:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah':
>     do_blah_thing()
> do_one()
> do_two()
> do_three()
> ```
>
> Rather not:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()
> do_one(); do_two(); do_three()
> ```

So, in your case:

Bad:

```
for state in states: score += penalty if state == bad else bonus
```

Better:

```
for state in states:
    score += penalty if state == bad else bonus
```

Best:

```
for state in states:
    if state == bad:
        score += penalty
    else:
        score += bonus
```

As matter of design style, not necessarily coding style, I might rather see state-specific score increments stored in a mapping object, like so:

```
for state in states:
    score += scores_per_state[state]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`sum`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
score += sum(penalty if state == bad else bonus
             for state in states)
```

Comment: That's an interesting method

Answer (score 0):

As Rob menitoned, you really should refer to the PEP standards for Python.  There is a huge community dedicated to defining what is okay and not okay when it comes to coding styles in Python...

python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008

I recommend starting there.

My suggestion for above, despite being very terse and compact, code has to be maintained eventually.  Always assume while you're coding that the person who has to maintain your code will be a crazy axe murderer who knows where you live.

Split your lines one operation or function per readable lines.  No one cares how fancy your code is if it's a pain to maintain.

Comment: List Comprehension is just one step separated from a lambda expression, which is quite defined and easier to comprehend vs cramming a whole lot of user defined functionality into one line instead of taking 5 lines to define a function.

Comment: when would you use ternary?

Comment: Personally? 
Well, myself and every consultant sitting within 8 desks of me agree that Ternary coding style should never exist in production code unless it's a lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

IMO, this is bad style. The first tenet of coding in a "professional environment" is "Can someone else maintain my code?"

First, it violates several of the guidelines in PEP8 regarding arrangement of code on one line.

Second, it combines code in a way that resembles comprehensions, without being one. This is needlessly confusing.

Finally, the ternary style in python is inherently sort of backwards. Unlike other languages, it uses value/condition/value, rather than condition/value/value. Unless that presentation matches the real-world conditions of your code (for example, providing a default value) you should use a structure that expresses what you want to convey in the right order:

```
for state in states:
    if state == bad:
        score += penalty
    else:
        score += bonus
```

The direction of the if/else statement might be reversed (`state != bad`) depending on how much typing or other expense is involved in the code. But otherwise, remember that you're trying to make life easier for someone (possibly YOU) brought in to "fix this old piece of crap" about 5 years from now.